# c# asp.net response.write shrinks text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Web Form project I am developing C# ASP.Net 4.5. I have a class that calls a response.write to display a message for user input validation purposes. The call to response.write is made inside the class in a method from creating a new instance of the class, thus the class method, by pressing a button on the form. But using the response.write causes the textboxes on my page to shrink considerably. Then when I press a different button the textboxes go back to normal. It only happens when I use response.write. Any help would be appreciated. Code call in class method:

```
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("File not found");
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use labels to display the message instead? To check what is causing the textbox shrink, use the dev tools of your browser (press F12) and analyze the elements.

Answer (score 0):

By using that you're simply dumping text to the top of the page, typically outside of the `<html>` tags. This can have a knock-on effect to the rest of the pages style; i see the same when i am spitting out test responses.

Instead, put yourself a label control on your page and populate that instead. you can put it exactly where you want and simply call:

So put this:  `<asp:Label runat="Server" id="myLabel" />` where you want the message to appear.

Then in your code-behind, write this. It will populate the label with the given text.

`myLabel.Text = "File not found";`

The `Label` control will be rendered as a `<span></span>` - so styling it is nice and easy.

If you fancied using a `<div>` then use the `Panel` control.

If you're not fussed about any sort of style, go for a `Literal` control, which renders no html elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write` on code behind is direct send to the page your text, at any random point of page render.

Maybe on top, maybe on bottom, on some point that you can not control if you use the code behind to call it.

Change the way you show your message, at a minimum you can use a literal control to render there your output and show it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a control to display your error. For example:

In the aspx/ascx

```
<asp:Label id="ErrorMessage" runat="server" />
```

in the page/control code behind

```
//call TheClass
TheClass c = new TheClass();
string error = c.TheMethod();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
{
    ErrorMessage.Text = error;
}
```

in TheClass

```
public class TheClass
{
    public string TheMethod()
    {
        string result = "";
        ...
        //When file is not found
        result = "File not found";
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```